# StdIn library in Netbeans - StdIn.readInt()

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm only a beginner with java currently studying at university, but for reasons i'll not go into I can't ask my tutor.

I'm having a problem using the StdIn library in Netbeans. In classes we use DrJava but since I can't get it to run on my Mac, i've resorted to Netbeans. In the following code, I can get it to run in Dr Java (it is a basic introduction to using standard input and output), but when i run it in netbeans, it throws a runtime error.

(i have included the StdIn.java and StdOut.java files in the same directory as the MaxMin.java file)

```
    public class MaxMin {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // first value read initialized min and max
    int max = StdIn.readInt();
    int min = max;

    // read in the data, keep track of min and max
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        int value = StdIn.readInt();
        if (value > max) max = value;
        if (value < min) min = value;
    }

    // output
    StdOut.println("maximum  = " + max + ", minimum = " + min);
}
```

I then get this runtime error in the netbeans output window.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: maxmin.StdIn.readInt
at maxmin.MaxMin.main(MaxMin.java:19)
    Java Result: 1
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I apologise for what must be a very basic problem, but i can't find any relevant help on this here in stack overflow.

I'm sure the code itself is ok as it is copied exactly from an online textbook:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/MaxMin.java.html

Can anyone shed some light on why Netbeans throws the runtime error instead of asking me for input?

EDIT
In response to a suggestion, I deselected 'Compile on save' in the project build options and then did the 'clean and build project'. and came up with these errors:

```
ant -f /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build
Updating property file: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/empty
Created dir: /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to /Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/build/classes
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/src/maxmin/MaxMin.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    int max = StdIn.readInt();
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class MaxMin
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/src/maxmin/MaxMin.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class MaxMin
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/src/maxmin/MaxMin.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        int value = StdIn.readInt();
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class MaxMin
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/src/maxmin/MaxMin.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            if (value < 0) StdOut.println("Please use positive values");
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class MaxMin
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/src/maxmin/MaxMin.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    StdOut.println("maximum  = " + max + ", minimum = " + min);
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class MaxMin
5 errors
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/nbproject/build-impl.xml:923: The following error         occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xUsernamex/NetBeansProjects/MaxMin/nbproject/build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the     compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It looks to me as if I'm having some issue with recognising the StdIn and StdOut libraries, but I'm not sure what to do about that. In Netbeans, which folder should I put them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs in netbeans if some classes are not compilable. you can try deselecting 'Compile On Save' in the project build options. Now clean&build your project and then run your code.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and now have further problems, any suggestions?