# StdOut & StdIn classes are not compilable on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a beginner to Java. Learning from 'Introduction to Java' by Robert Sedgewick & Kevin Wayne. (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/)

I tried compiling the following code in Netbeans.

```
public class Average {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double sum =0.0;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
    double value = StdIn.readDouble();
    sum += value;
    cnt++;
    }
    double average = sum/cnt;
    StdOut.println("Average is " + average);
}
```

}

I am getting this error. I have placed the files `StdOut.java` & `StdIn.java` at the appropriate folder `(Average/src)`. How to go about this problem?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: sample.StdIn.isEmpty
>       at sample.Average.main(Average.java:16)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Given your error, StdIn.java and StdOut.java need to go into `src/sample/`, not directly into `src/`

**xor**

Remove package declaration

```
  package sample;
```

from both StdIn.java and StdOut.java

You might be missing an

```
import sample.*;
```

in your own class?

Comment: Wrote it incorrectly in the question. Those files are in src/sample itself. Now what to do? 
Thanks!

Comment: A similar question was asked previously 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608841/stdin-library-in-netbeans-stdin-readint

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the StdOut.java and StdIn.java in Average.java.

something like this:

if `StdOut.java` and `StdIn.java` are inside `src/com/mycompany/util` package

```
import com.mycompany.util

public class Average{

---------------------
---------------------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit here is actually *very* misleading.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: sample.StdIn.isEmpty at sample.Average.main(Average.java:16) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I think you're looking at a NetBeans problem, not a Java one.

Close NetBeans and try deleting this folder:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\<NetBeans Version>`

(The actual folder location depends on Netbeans/Windows version. potentially you need to look in `C:\Users\<username>\.netbeans` instead.)